# Produce current

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, generator, emf

Ok, so I was trying our an experiment to generate minute current. I got a battery operated gear motor which can produce current to light ant led bulb when rotated. I am trying to create an automation for rotating it continuously.

So what I am trying to do is to attach magnets facing all South faces outwards to a circular disc. And activate the repel action using another magnet, assuming it would rotate continuously life tine.

1) is my approach good?
2) what is the maximum current I can get?
3) where can I find kit or step by step detailed instructions for my experiment :(? Yea I know the process but I am finding difficult to construct the hardware like.. Making a freely rotating disc. With less cost

Comment: Have you heard of the principle of conservation of energy?

Comment: Yes....I am just trying to rotate a disc...

Comment: Perhaps a read through [Patents for Unworkable Devices](https://www.lhup.edu/~dsimanek/museum/patents.htm) would be an appropriate read.

Comment: On this stack we obey the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: What 'transistor' says is good. Trying to get something for nothing energy wise never works, unfortunately. Devices that try or claim to do this are called "perpetual motion machines", "over unity devices" and similar. Some claim good results. Alas, ALL such to date are either deluded or liars. Be **VERY** careful re any claims to be able to do this.

Comment: I agree with transistor..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No. Your approach is not good. You are trying to create energy out of nothing. This is against the law (of conservation of energy). The flaw in this case is that you are only imagining the force acting on the magnet moving away forgetting that there is an opposite force on the magnet that is moving closer. The forces cancel out. No rotation.
2. Maximum current you can get? Zero.
3. You will find kits for this sort of project from scammers. A quick web search for "free energy" will give you plenty of hits.

Look up the law of conservation of energy and then have a look at the various "free energy" schemes and see if you can figure out where the flaw is in each.